# Drawing free body diagram of all wires and masses as given in the figure

Tags: free-body-diagram

[image]

[image]

Are these FBD diagrams correct? I have drawn them considering the Al and Cu wires as massless.

I just had to find the net force acting on the copper and aluminium wire. Is there an easier way to do that directly, anything less cumbersome than drawing the FBDs?

Comment: If the wires are massless then the net force on them must be zero.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @Farcher But there is no other force to balance the forces on Al and Cu wires. Then how will the two wires ever be in equilibrium under the assumption. that they are massless.The question was actually about finding the net elongation in the wires due to the stress created on loading the two masses. I was previously thinking that the stress will be due to the net external force but since it is zero, what force will now cause stress? Tension force? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the wires are assumed massless, then by a=F/m acceleration of these wires become infinite which is not possible.
To prevent this condition net force must be zero on the wires if they have a finite acceleration.
Infact on any massless object which cannot have infinite acceleration netforce is zero. Also, it looks like system has attained equilibrium.

Comment: I think I addressed all the forces. What other forces might balance the tension force on the two wires?

Comment: For Al you did not mentioncthe force by fixed surface

Comment: And for Cu, you have broken the third law, the tension and M2g are on different objects

Comment: The question was actually about finding the net elongation in the wires due to the stress created on loading the two masses. I was previously thinking that the stress will be due to the net external force but since it is zero, what force will now cause stress? Tension force? Why?

Comment: Yeah you are right about the Cu case. That m2g should not be there.

Comment: Why not, stress is generally caused due to forces that are applied on both sides

Comment: I think I am getting the idea where I was wrong. Thank you.